# How to change what port Safari is trying to use to access websites?

Tags: tfs, safari

I'm trying to access TFS on a Safari browser, but every time I try to enter credentials to access TFS, I'm not allowed access.

I believe this is due to Safari trying to use the wrong port. It asks me to connect to `tfs.blahblah.com:443`. While in Chrome it asks to connect to `tfs.blahblah.com:8080`. I have no issues connecting when using Chrome.

Can someone offer some guidance?

Comment: Did you try specifying a protocol, like `http://tfs.blahblah.com:8080`? The default behavior for modern browsers is to use https unless explicitly told otherwise.

Comment: Just tried it. The progress bar is stuck at the very beginning and doesn't even prompt me to enter my credentials :(